# Vimeo API 3.2: Is it possible to search "my" videos? me/videos?query does not seem to work

Tags: vimeo-api

I would like to search the list of videos I have uploaded for specific tags / words in the title.

**Is it possible to use the query keyword to search videos? What does it search?** I am asking, because despite me having multiple titles containing the word "overview", when I use this call

```
https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/me/videos?query=overview
```

I get no results. If I remove the query, I get all videos.

**Is it possible to search my videos for tags?** 
I would like to have my newly posted videos to appear in the appropriate section of a single page app, based on their tag. Is this achievable?

Thank you.

Comment: Are your videos private? Are you a PRO user in private mode?

Comment: Yes, I am a PRO user, and the videos are private. I am not sure what "PRO user in private mode" means.

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo's search does not currently support private videos. This will change in the near future, but until that does there is only one workaround.

Check https://vimeo.com/settings. If you are a PRO user and have Private Mode active, your search terms use a less powerful search system that supports private videos. This search only includes terms in the body of your video.

If you are not a Private PRO member, only public videos will show up in search. In those searches tags are a default part of the search query along with title and body. You can not yet limit your request to single search facet.

Comment: Thank you. I think I will use the api to collect all data about "my" videos and add them to a database for quick, easy and flexible queries. It is unfortunate that the vimeo API does not mention this restriction (at least I could not find it in the documentation) -- looks like the query option should work for all user viceos.